# Remove Object from Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove an object from an array?
I wish to remove the object that includes name `Kristian` from `someArray`. For example:

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

I want to achieve:

```
someArray = [{name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

Answer (score 1029, accepted):

You can use several methods to remove item(s) from an Array:

```
//1
someArray.shift(); // first element removed
//2
someArray = someArray.slice(1); // first element removed
//3
someArray.splice(0, 1); // first element removed
//4
someArray.pop(); // last element removed
//5
someArray = someArray.slice(0, someArray.length - 1); // last element removed
//6
someArray.length = someArray.length - 1; // last element removed
```

If you want to remove element at position `x`, use:

```
someArray.splice(x, 1);
```

Or

```
someArray = someArray.slice(0, x).concat(someArray.slice(-x));
```

Reply to the comment of [@chill182](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995721/chill182): you can remove one or more elements from an array using `Array.filter`, or `Array.splice` combined with `Array.findIndex` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

See this [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-7qzbck?file=script.js) or the snippet below:

```js
// non destructive filter > noJohn = John removed, but someArray will not change
let someArray = getArray();
let noJohn = someArray.filter( el => el.name !== "John" ); 
log(`let noJohn = someArray.filter( el => el.name !== "John")`,
  `non destructive filter [noJohn] =`, format(noJohn));
log(`**someArray.length ${someArray.length}`);

// destructive filter/reassign John removed > someArray2 =
let someArray2 = getArray();
someArray2 = someArray2.filter( el => el.name !== "John" );
log("", 
  `someArray2 = someArray2.filter( el => el.name !== "John" )`,
  `destructive filter/reassign John removed [someArray2] =`, 
  format(someArray2));
log(`**someArray2.length after filter ${someArray2.length}`);

// destructive splice /w findIndex Brian remains > someArray3 =
let someArray3 = getArray();
someArray3.splice(someArray3.findIndex(v => v.name === "Kristian"), 1);
someArray3.splice(someArray3.findIndex(v => v.name === "John"), 1);
log("",
  `someArray3.splice(someArray3.findIndex(v => v.name === "Kristian"), 1),`,
  `destructive splice /w findIndex Brian remains [someArray3] =`, 
  format(someArray3));
log(`**someArray3.length after splice ${someArray3.length}`);

// if you're not sure about the contents of your array, 
// you should check the results of findIndex first
let someArray4 = getArray();
const indx = someArray4.findIndex(v => v.name === "Michael");
someArray4.splice(indx, indx >= 0 ? 1 : 0);
log("", `someArray4.splice(indx, indx >= 0 ? 1 : 0)`,
  `check findIndex result first [someArray4] = (nothing is removed)`,
  format(someArray4));
log(`**someArray4.length (should still be 3) ${someArray4.length}`);

// -- helpers -- 
function format(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, null, " ");
}

function log(...txt) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += `${txt.join("\n")}\n`
}

function getArray() {
  return [ {name: "Kristian", lines: "2,5,10"},
           {name: "John", lines: "1,19,26,96"},
           {name: "Brian", lines: "3,9,62,36"} ];
}
```

```html
<pre>
**Results**

</pre>
```

Comment: @Klemzy didnt you mean not by index ? by value ...?

Comment: The original question asked how to remove the object with the name="Kristian" from the array. Your answer assumes it's the first item in the array but what if Kristin is not in the first item? Then your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @chill182: it's not a specific answer, but a more general one. From it, you should be able to infer the method to remove elements. *If you want to remove element at position x* ... may be a hint for removing other than first elements, right?

Comment: The splice function was helpful to me, but you shouldn't have re-assigned someArray. This will result in someArray containing the removed item, instead of it containing the resulting array with the item removed.

Comment: another thing i  want, There will be separate buttons for every object in array. if i want to delete that particular object in the array button clicked. how to do it . i have used angular js ng-repeat to generate items.  can you help me

Comment: Technically, it's another array that doesn't include John.

Comment: You should check the `findIndex` result before using it in `splice`. If there are no elements in the array that match the condition `findIndex` will return `-1`and putting this directly into `splice` will result in an arbitraty deletion of the last element in the array.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer...?

Answer (score 317):

The clean solution would be to use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filtered = someArray.filter(function(el) { return el.Name != "Kristian"; });
```

The problem with this is that it [does not work](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) on IE < 9. However, you can include code from a Javascript library (e.g. [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#filter)) that implements this for any browser.

Comment: This however will remove all the occurrences found, not only the first one

Comment: And it will return a new array instead of modifying the original one. Depending on the use case, this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @JochieNabuurs it is indeed a new array. However, the object remains the same. You can still modify each object's value and it will reflect on the original array's object.

Comment: To the point about this returning a new array, just changing the solution to `someArray = someArray.filter(function(el) { return el.Name != "Kristian"; }); ` addresses that, no?

Comment: It will work, doubtless. But if you are concerning about memory management it will create a new object anyway. I don't wanna me picky, this is gonna work for quite any case.  But if for any reason you are dealing with a really large array, you should handle  removing elements using the same object.

Comment: There is a shorter way of doing this `var filtered = someArray.filter(el => { return el.Name != "Kristian"; });`

Comment: This is a much simpler and more direct answer to the question asked than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 149):

I recommend using lodash.js or [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) for common tasks like this:

```
// lodash.js
someArray = _.reject(someArray, function(el) { return el.Name === "Kristian"; });

// sugar.js
someArray.remove(function(el) { return el.Name === "Kristian"; });
```

in most projects, having a set of helper methods that is provided by libraries like these is quite useful.

Comment: I think the underscore example is slightly off. Should be `someArray = _.reject(someArray, function(el) { return el.Name === "Kristian"; });`

Comment: If you don't want to use underscore.js or sugar.js, you can do this `someArray = someArray.filter(function(e) { return e.Name !== "Kristian"; });`

Comment: @AndyFord You can chain methods in _.js so both will work although I think he needs to a call to .value() at the end.

Comment: another thing i  want, There will be separate buttons for every object in array. if i want to delete that particular object in the array button clicked. how to do it . i have used angular js ng-repeat to generate items.  can you help me

Comment: sugar.js was the best thing I've came across today. Thanks for this, even if it is 4 years later... :)

Comment: Going to go against the grain here; suggesting one include an entire library for the simple purpose of removing items from objects (which js cleanly supports out of the box, as the accepted answer shows) is poor form.  It adds unnecessary weight and complexity to your code unless you already need it for the more powerful functionality the library provides.

Comment: what if there are two conditions for Sugar.js, ie `el.Name === "Kristian"` and `el.Course === "I.T."` ??

Comment: For simple operation , i will never recommend to include library

Comment: This is a bad answer, including a whole library just for using one simple operation method will increase the whole download size of your application and thus making it unnecessary slow to load over the web.

Answer (score 128):

ES2015

```
let someArray = [
               {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
               {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
               {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,58,160"},
               {name:"Felix", lines:"1,19,26,96"}
            ];

someArray = someArray.filter(person => person.name != 'John');
```

It will remove **John**!

Comment: Man... Coming from java, I'm highgly confused that such a basic thing to do requires filtering of a list... wtf. This is the most accurate answer to OPs question I read so far.

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. Though it will also work prior to ES2015(ES6). The filter function has been available since version 5.1(2011) https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20

Comment: Nice and clean :)

Comment: I use this one-line-solution with success in my case, it is very adaptive too : the condition can easily be customized.

Comment: Note that this will remove all occurrences, not just the first.

Answer (score 94):

How about this?

```
$.each(someArray, function(i){
    if(someArray[i].name === 'Kristian') {
        someArray.splice(i,1);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't that cause an error because `$.each()` caches the array length before looping so if you remove an element `$.each()` will run past the end of the (now shorter) array. (So then `someArray[i]` will be `undefined` and `undefined.name` will crash.)

Comment: Then add a 'return false' after the splice.

Comment: this is not javascript. -1

Comment: Please note that this answer requires jQuery

Answer (score 76):

Your "array" as shown is invalid JavaScript syntax. Curly brackets `{}` are for objects with property name/value pairs, but square brackets `[]` are for arrays - like so:

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"}, {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

In that case, you can use the [`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an item. To remove the first item (index 0), say:

```
someArray.splice(0,1);

// someArray = [{name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

If you don't know the index but want to search through the array to find the item with name "Kristian" to remove you could to this:

```
for (var i =0; i < someArray.length; i++)
   if (someArray[i].name === "Kristian") {
      someArray.splice(i,1);
      break;
   }
```

EDIT: I just noticed your question is tagged with "jQuery", so you could try the [`$.grep()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
someArray = $.grep(someArray,
                   function(o,i) { return o.name === "Kristian"; },
                   true);
```

Comment: Why did they add the overload? Surely you could have just put != "Kristian". What purpose does the overload serve?

Comment: @markthewizard1234 - Do you mean the "invert" Boolean argument in `$.grep()`?  It doesn't add much in this example, where yes, I could've put `!=`, but in other cases you might already have a function defined that happens to do the opposite test to what you want to grep, so then rather than defining an additional function you can just use that overload to invert the results.

Comment: Ah, so if you had a wrapper function containing the grep you could set the boolean as a parameter. Got it thanks!

Comment: @markthewizard1234 - You could, but that's not what I had in mind: imagine you had `function isEven(num) { return num%2===0 }`. You could use `$.grep(someArray, isEven)` to get just the even numbers from the array, or `$.grep(someArray, isEven, true)` to do the opposite and get the non-even values.

Answer (score 60):

You could use array.filter().

e.g.

```
        someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
                     {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];

        someArray = someArray.filter(function(returnableObjects){
               return returnableObjects.name !== 'Kristian';
        });

        //someArray will now be = [{name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

Arrow functions:

```
someArray = someArray.filter(x => x.name !== 'Kristian')
```

Comment: another thing i  want, There will be separate buttons for every object in array. if i want to delete that particular object in the array button clicked. how to do it . i have used angular js ng-repeat to generate items.  can you help me

Comment: daCoda what if you have two conditions?

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador say for example if you have another conditions you can write this like below and continue with different && or || operator according to your need.

someArray = someArray.filter(function(returnableObjects){
    return returnableObjects.name !== 'Kristian' && cond2Query.age >= 22;
});

Answer (score 23):

```
const someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"}, {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
```

We get the index of the object which have name property value as "Kristian"

```
const index = someArray.findIndex(key => key.name === "Kristian");
console.log(index); // 0
```

By using splice function we are removing the object which have the name property value as "Kristian"

```
someArray.splice(index,1);
console.log(someArray); // [{name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}]
```

Comment: One of the perfect answer. The rest above was such a waste of time.

Comment: @sg28 Thanks a lot ,i saw nobody explained it

Answer (score 21):

This is a function that works for me:

```
function removeFromArray(array, value) {
    var idx = array.indexOf(value);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        array.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I have made a dynamic function takes the objects Array, Key and value and returns the same array after removing the desired object:

```
function removeFunction (myObjects,prop,valu)
        {
             return myObjects.filter(function (val) {
              return val[prop] !== valu;
          });

        }
```

Full Example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aPH7m/1/)

```
var obj = {
            "results": [
              {
                  "id": "460",
                  "name": "Widget 1",
                  "loc": "Shed"
              }, {
                  "id": "461",
                  "name": "Widget 2",
                  "loc": "Kitchen"
              }, {
                  "id": "462",
                  "name": "Widget 3",
                  "loc": "bath"
              }
            ]
            };


        function removeFunction (myObjects,prop,valu)
        {
             return myObjects.filter(function (val) {
              return val[prop] !== valu;
          });

        }


console.log(removeFunction(obj.results,"id","460"));
```

Answer (score 16):

You could also try doing something like this:

```
var myArray = [{'name': 'test'}, {'name':'test2'}];
var myObject = {'name': 'test'};
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(myObject),1);
```

Comment: `myArray.indexOf(myObject)` returns -1, because no item was reference-equal to `myObject`. so `splice()` removes the -1th element in the array, which in this case is `{'name':'test2'}`!

Answer (score 12):

```
someArray = jQuery.grep(someArray , function (value) {
        return value.name != 'Kristian';
});
```

Answer (score 11):

## Performance

Today 2021.01.27 I perform tests on MacOs HighSierra 10.13.6 on Chrome v88, Safari v13.1.2 and Firefox v84 for chosen solutions.

### Results

For all browsers:

- fast/fastest solutions when element not exists: A and B
- fast/fastest solutions for big arrays: C
- fast/fastest solutions for big arrays when element exists: H
- quite slow solutions for small arrays: F and G
- quite slow solutions for big arrays: D, E and F

[image]

### Details

I perform 4 tests cases:

- small array (10 elements) and element exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/1skk6tqmiv/1)
- small array (10 elements) and element NOT exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/wmkk6tsiwg/1)
- big array (milion elements) and element exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/j0kkfb2t9c/1)
- big array (milion elements) and element NOT exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/xwkkfbson2)

Below snippet presents differences between solutions
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024926/860099)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024926/860099)
[C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025321/860099)
[D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024929/860099)
[E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606805/860099)
[F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024964/860099)
[G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658809/860099)
[H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113835/860099)
[I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887990/860099)

```js
function A(arr, name) {
  let idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.name==name);
  if(idx>=0) arr.splice(idx, 1);
  return arr;
}


function B(arr, name) {
  let idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.name==name);
  return idx<0 ? arr : arr.slice(0,idx).concat(arr.slice(idx+1,arr.length));
}


function C(arr, name) {
  let idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.name==name);
  delete arr[idx];
  return arr;
}


function D(arr, name) {
  return arr.filter(el => el.name != name);
}


function E(arr, name) {
  let result = [];
  arr.forEach(o => o.name==name || result.push(o));
  return result;
}


function F(arr, name) {
  return _.reject(arr, el => el.name == name);
}


function G(arr, name) {
  let o = arr.find(o => o.name==name);
  return _.without(arr,o);
}


function H(arr, name) {
  $.each(arr, function(i){
      if(arr[i].name === 'Kristian') {
          arr.splice(i,1);
          return false;
      }
  });
  return arr;
}


function I(arr, name) {
  return $.grep(arr,o => o.name!=name);
}








// Test
let test1 = [   
    {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
    {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},  
];

let test2 = [   
    {name:"John3", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
    {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
    {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
  {name:"Joh2", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
];

let test3 = [   
    {name:"John3", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
    {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
  {name:"Joh2", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
];

console.log(`
Test1: original array from question
Test2: array with more data
Test3: array without element which we want to delete
`);

[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I].forEach(f=> console.log(`
Test1 ${f.name}: ${JSON.stringify(f([...test1],"Kristian"))}
Test2 ${f.name}: ${JSON.stringify(f([...test2],"Kristian"))}
Test3 ${f.name}: ${JSON.stringify(f([...test3],"Kristian"))}
`));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
  
This shippet only presents functions used in performance tests - it not perform tests itself!
```

And here are example results for chrome

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use splice function on arrays. Specify the position of the start element and the length of the subsequence you want to remove.

```
someArray.splice(pos, 1);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example with map and splice

```js
const arrayObject = [
  { name: "name1", value: "value1" },
  { name: "name2", value: "value2" },
  { name: "name3", value: "value3" },
];

let index = arrayObject.map((item) => item.name).indexOf("name1");
if (index > -1) {
  arrayObject.splice(index, 1);
  console.log("Result", arrayObject);
}
```

**Output**

```
Result [
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "value": "value2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "value": "value3"
  }
]
```

Comment: This will also work in IE11, while answers with `findIndex` won't.

Answer (score 9):

Vote for the [UndercoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) for simple work with arrays.

[_.without()](http://underscorejs.org/#without) function helps to remove an element:

```
 _.without([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], 0, 1);
    => [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The best solution. Works with object arrays.

Answer (score 6):

With ES 6 arrow function

```
let someArray = [
                 {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
                 {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}
                ];
let arrayToRemove={name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"};
someArray=someArray.filter((e)=>e.name !=arrayToRemove.name && e.lines!= arrayToRemove.lines)
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this is probably not that appropriate for this situation I found out the other day that you can also use the `delete` keyword to remove an item from an array if you don't need to alter the size of the array e.g.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];

delete myArray[1];

console.log(myArray[1]); //undefined

console.log(myArray.length); //3 - doesn't actually shrink the array down
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution would be to create a map that stores the indexes for each object by name, like this:

```
//adding to array
var newPerson = {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"}
someMap[ newPerson.name ] = someArray.length;
someArray.push( newPerson );

//deleting from the array
var index = someMap[ 'Kristian' ];
someArray.splice( index, 1 );
```

Comment: I like this idea, but must also ask, what are the memory use limits for an idea like this as indexes are added?  I have an array that I'd like to index on 2 different fields in the object, so I'd have 2 maps in addition to the original source array.  Is this a small price to pay for lookup speed or is there a solution that would be more efficient with memory?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **map** function also.

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},{name:"John",lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
newArray=[];
someArray.map(function(obj, index){
    if(obj.name !== "Kristian"){
       newArray.push(obj);
    }
});
someArray = newArray;
console.log(someArray);
```

Comment: But if you want to iterate through the array, isn't it better to use forEach ?

Comment: map() does iterate through an array.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all occurrences of a given object (based on some condition) then use the javascript splice method inside a for the loop.

Since removing an object would affect the array length, make sure to decrement the counter one step, so that length check remains intact.

```
var objArr=[{Name:"Alex", Age:62},
  {Name:"Robert", Age:18},
  {Name:"Prince", Age:28},
  {Name:"Cesar", Age:38},
  {Name:"Sam", Age:42},
  {Name:"David", Age:52}
];

for(var i = 0;i < objArr.length; i ++)
{
  if(objArr[i].Age > 20)
  {
    objArr.splice(i, 1);
    i--;  //re-adjust the counter.
  }
}
```

The above code snippet removes all objects with age greater than 20.

Answer (score 3):

This answer

```
for (var i =0; i < someArray.length; i++)
   if (someArray[i].name === "Kristian") {
      someArray.splice(i,1);
   }
```

is not working for multiple records fulfilling the condition. If you have two such consecutive records, only the first one is removed, and the other one skipped. You have to use:

```
for (var i = someArray.length - 1; i>= 0; i--)
   ...
```

instead .

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answers are very branched and knotted.

You can use the following path to remove an array object that matches the object given in the modern JavaScript jargon.

```js
coordinates = [
    { lat: 36.779098444109145, lng: 34.57202827508546 },
    { lat: 36.778754712956506, lng: 34.56898128564454 },
    { lat: 36.777414146732426, lng: 34.57179224069215 }
];

coordinate = { lat: 36.779098444109145, lng: 34.57202827508546 };

removeCoordinate(coordinate: Coordinate): Coordinate {
    const found = this.coordinates.find((coordinate) => coordinate == coordinate);
    if (found) {
      this.coordinates.splice(found, 1);
    }
    return coordinate;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error in your array syntax so assuming you mean an array as opposed to an object, [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is your friend here:

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"}, {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];
someArray.splice(1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript's splice() function.

This may help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];

someArray.some(item => { 
    if(item.name === "Kristian") // Case sensitive, will only remove first instance
        someArray.splice(someArray.indexOf(item),1) 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use.

```
Array.prototype.delete = function(pos){
    this[pos] = undefined;
    var len = this.length - 1;
    for(var a = pos;a < this.length - 1;a++){
      this[a] = this[a+1];
    }
    this.pop();
  }
```

Then it is as simple as saying

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
myArray.delete(3);
```

Replace any number in place of three. After the expected output should be:

```
console.log(myArray); //Expected output 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Your delete function is just a worse version of `splice`.

Answer (score 1):

splice(i, 1) where i is the incremental index of the array will remove the object. 
But remember splice will also reset the array length so watch out for 'undefined'. Using your example, if you remove 'Kristian', then in the next execution within the loop, i will be 2 but someArray will be a length of 1, therefore if you try to remove "John" you will get an "undefined" error. One solution to this albeit not elegant is to have separate counter to keep track of index of the element to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Returns only objects from the array whose property `name` is not "Kristian"

```
var noKristianArray = $.grep(someArray, function (el) { return el.name!= "Kristian"; });
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
 var someArray = [
                {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
                {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
                {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,58,160"},
                {name:"Felix", lines:"1,19,26,96"}
                ];
    
var noKristianArray = $.grep(someArray, function (el) { return el.name!= "Kristian"; });

console.log(noKristianArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter like this:

```js
const someArray = [{
    name: "Kristian",
    lines: "2,5,10"
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    lines: "1,19,26,96"
  }
];
var filtered = someArray.filter((el) => el.name != "Kristian");
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Concepts using Kendo Grid

```
var grid = $("#addNewAllergies").data("kendoGrid");

var selectedItem = SelectedCheckBoxList;

for (var i = 0; i < selectedItem.length; i++) {
    if(selectedItem[i].boolKendoValue==true)
    {
        selectedItem.length= 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any properties on the objects in the array that you know (or perhaps that are unique), but you have a reference to the object that you want to remove, you can do what's in the `unregisterObject` method below:

```js
let registeredObjects = [];

function registerObject(someObject) { registeredObjects.push(someObject); }
function unregisterObject(someObject) { registeredObjects = registeredObjects.filter(obj => obj !== someObject); }

let myObject1 = {hidden: "someValue1"}; // Let's pretend we don't know the hidden attribute
let myObject2 = {hidden: "someValue2"};

registerObject(myObject1);
registerObject(myObject2);
console.log(`There are ${registeredObjects.length} objects registered. They are: ${JSON.stringify(registeredObjects)}`);

unregisterObject(myObject1);
console.log(`There are ${registeredObjects.length} objects registered. They are: ${JSON.stringify(registeredObjects)}`);
```