# How to remove object from Array and save it for use later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Originally my question was [**How to Remove Object from jQuery array**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript). < Found the answer, the one from @nnnnnn. Using `$.grep`

My new question now is how would you save the object that you just removed?

Reason is I wish to be able to push that saved Object back into the Array if the user decides to keep it.

My `networks` array:

console:
`networks array = [object Object],[object Object]`

```
networks: Array[2]
    0: Object
      count: 1
      id: "6"
      label: "CompanyName"
      type: "Organization"

    1: Object
      count: 1
      id: "12622"
      label: "MyGroup"
      type: "Group"
```

From the other answer I'm using this to look in the **networks** array, find the **Object** with the type of **"Organization"** and remove it.

`networks = $.grep(networks, function(o,i) { return o.type === "Organization"; }, true);`

Is there a simple way to save that entire Object? So it can be pushed back in?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Before you return from the callback, save the object in a variable. It's not super clean but works.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I just ran this function actually and the `$.grep` did not remove the object form the function :( may be back at square 1

Comment: Oh wait lol, it does work `type not name`.. ok I'll try what you recommended

Comment: It should though, that's what `$.grep` is doing. Note that you are using `o.name` in the callback, but your example data doesn't have a `name` property. *edit:* Yep ;)

Comment: another thing i want, There will be separate buttons for every object in array. if i want to delete that particular object in the array button clicked and that should be move to another secondary array.  how to do it . i have used angular js ng-repeat to generate items. can you help me

Comment: @ThilakRaj that should be pretty easy, just check the object you clicked on. Compare some key in it, like `id` or `name` whatever, and you can use a simple `for loop` or `lodash` to find it in the main array and then remove it there. Use `splice`.

Comment: Can you show me using this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/eKY6vrPtvaKstgcY0g3I?p=preview
Secondary items will be displayed at right. primary array items will be displayed left

Comment: @ThilakRaj https://plnkr.co/edit/ubAPmJoMQaKBLvWSsmTv?p=preview btw never name Object keys with capital letters ie `Name` always just `name`. Check out this Stackoverflow btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the object inside the callback to a variable. This isn't a very clean solution, since such callbacks shouldn't have side effects IMO, but it works without making bigger changes to your code:

```
var obj;
networks = $.grep(networks, function(o,i) {
  if (o.type === "Organization") {
      obj = o;
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}, true);
```

or a bit shorter (and more confusing for people who don't know about the comma operator):

```
var obj;
networks = $.grep(networks, function(o,i) { 
    return o.type === "Organization" ? ((obj = o), true) : false;
}, true);
```

Comment: another thing i want, There will be separate buttons for every object in array. if i want to delete that particular object in the array button clicked. how to do it . i have used angular js ng-repeat to generate items. can you help me