# How to remove and re-add specific objects by id into Array [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I asked a similar question here: [How to remove and save object from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315590/how-to-remove-object-from-array-and-save-it-for-use-later)

It worked when I just needed to check the type of the object ("Group" or "Organization") However I need to get more specific now and need to find objects by ID and remove / re-add them into the Array.

However when I try to adapt the code to check for an Object's id, I either can't find and remove the ID or I end up removing all the Objects from the Array.

```
// re-add Group to networks (This works great)
if (isChecked === 'checked') {

    var group_obj = {
        'id': name
    }

    networks.push(group_obj);

// remove Group from networks (Problem exist in the else if)
} else if (isChecked === undefined) {

    var group_obj = {
        'id': name
    }

    var removeItem = group_obj;

    var obj;
    networks = $.grep(networks, function(o,i) {

        console.log('removeItem.id = '+removeItem.id);
        console.log('name = '+name);

        if (removeItem.id === name) {
            obj = o;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }, true);
}

console.log(networks);
```

*Console*
What my networks Array looks like before I take action on the checkboxes:

```
[Object, Object, Object]

0: Object
    count: 1
    id: 6
    label: "Who"
    type: "Organization"

1: Object
    id: 12622

2: Object
    id: 13452
```

When the checkbox to the corresponding group is unchecked, the current code above will remove **all Objects from the Array are removed** instead of just the specified group object.

```
[]
```

When the checkbox is then checked again, the selected group will enter the Array.

I also tried this at first:

```
var obj;
networks = $.grep(networks, function(o,i) { 
    return o.id === name ? ((obj = o), true) : false;
}, true);
```

However again it does not find and remove the Object in the array with the specified id (`name`) but it leaves the networks Array untouched.

How would you write the `else if` statement to correct remove just the Object with the specified id and leave the rest of the Objects in the Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should u se filter instead of the grep, like this :

```
networks = networks.filter(function (o,i) {
     return o.id !== name ? ((obj = o), true) : false;
});
```

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing. check out this super simple fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wKty/