# How to remove an object from an array based on given property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  { content: "lelzz", post_id: "241" },
  { content: "zzyzz", post_id: "242" },
  { content: "abcde", post_id: "242" },
  { content: "12345", post_id: "242" },
  { content: "nomno", post_id: "243" }
]
```

How can I remove all objects with a `post_id` of `'242'`?

Comment: Here are a few ways to remove an element from an array in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. loop through array backwards
2. [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for indices with the matching property

```
function removeObjectsWithPostId (arr, id) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (arr[i].post_id === id) arr.splice(i, 1)
    }
    return arr
}
```

If you know that there might be more than one object with this property, you should instead prefer [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function removeObjectsWithPostId (arr, id) {
    return arr.filter(function (obj) { return obj.post_id !== id })
}
```