# my splice doesn't work in deleteing array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use ng-repeat, I did the unshift which adds a new item into a list. but I have problem with deleting an item.

this is console.log($scope.postItem)

[image]

and I tried this:

```
var itemsLength = $scope.postItem.length;

for(var i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++){
 if($scope.postItem[i].post_id == get_post_id){
  $scope.postItem.splice(i,1);
  break;
  }
 }
```

it doesn't work because it removed the entire thing. I should be getting the index of the founded $scope.postItem[i] before splice.

Comment: Didn't you just ask [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691730/delete-item-using-splice-for-javascript-object/21691829#21691829)

Comment: @clancer I may be blind, but doesn't one box say 241 and the other 242?

Comment: Please show more code