# Trying to randomize words from an array and stop the loop after 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a script that will pick a random word from an array called words, and stop the loop after 5 times and replace the html with Amazing. so it always ends on amazing. Can't figure out best practice for something like this. My thinking is there just don't know where to put the script ender or how to properly implement this.

I feel like I need to implement something like this into my script, but can't figure out where. Please help.

```
if(myLoop > 15) {
    console.log(myLoop);
    $("h1").html('AMAZING.'); 
}
else {
}
```

Here is the Javascript that I'm using to loop and create bring new words in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    words = ['respected​', 'essential', 'tactical', 'effortless', 'credible', 'smart', 'lucid', 'engaging', 'focussed', 'effective', 'clear', 'relevant', 'strategic', 'trusted', 'compelling', 'admired', 'inspiring', 'cogent', 'impactful', 'valued']

    var timer     = 2000,
        fadeSpeed =  500;

    var count = words.length;
    var position, x, myLoop;

    $("h1").html(words[rand(count)]);

    function rand(count) {
        x = position;
        position = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        if (position != x) {
            return position;
        } else {
            rand(count);
        }
    }

    function newWord() {
        //clearTimeout(myLoop); //clear timer

        // get new random number
        position = rand(count);


        // change tagline
        $("h1").fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
            $("h1").slideDown('slow'); $(this).html(words[position]).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);        
        });

        myLoop = setTimeout(function() {newWord()}, timer);
    }

    myLoop = setTimeout(function() {newWord()}, timer);
});
```

Here's my codepen

http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/bNwewb

Comment: I think start by checking the previous world, and make sure they don't repeat is a start.

Comment: On that note, you have to check *every* previous word. Also, "focussed" should be spelled "focused."

Comment: Just shuffle the array, then slice() it down to 4 elements and push "amazing" as last element in new array. Can find lots of array shuffle techniques on this site

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know how to implement that into my script.

Comment: @mbomb007 haha thanks for the spell check, How would I go about doing that check?

Comment: @wlin Not sure how to check words and make sure they don't repeat...

Comment: Shuffle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript  then...[SLice()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: It's pretty simple to check previously selected words. When the word is chosen in the `else` statement I added, remove it from the array `words'.

Comment: If you are interested in performance, it's faster to remove an element from a linked list. See this link for implementing a linked list instead of an array: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/5328-javascript-data-structures-the-linked-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, which uses a `for` loop and a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Words are removed from the array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).  This prevents repeats.

I'm using jQuery [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in place of `setTimeout`:

```js
var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

words = ['respected​', 'essential', 'tactical', 'effortless', 'credible', 'smart', 'lucid', 'engaging', 'focused', 'effective', 'clear', 'relevant', 'strategic', 'trusted', 'compelling', 'admired', 'inspiring', 'cogent', 'impactful', 'valued'];

fadeSpeed =  500;
timer = 2000;

for(i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++) {
  if(i===5) {
    word= 'awesome';
  }
  else {
    rnd= Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    word= words[rnd];
    words.splice(rnd, 1);
  }
  
  (function(word) {
    $('h1').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
             $(this).html(word);
           })
           .slideDown('slow')
           .delay(timer)
           .fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
   }
  )(word);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: You Rule Dude! So concise and way less lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I actually thought of this overnight, how you could use a loop rather than calling the function from within itself. It's good to see that this is pretty much would it would've become after the changes I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I added an iteration counter to check how many times it has changed.

Added this by other variables:

```
var iter = 1;
```

Added this in the `newWord` function:

```
iter = iter + 1;
if (iter > 5) {
  return;
}

var word;
if (iter == 5) {
  word = 'awesome';
}
else {
...
```

Here's my solution by changing your code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPGWYd

Comment: Thank you so much! does this also solve the repeating words scenario?

Comment: No, it does not. It is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: how does the reader go about doing that :] ? wouldn't I need some sort of database that tracks all words already used?

Comment: I already commented about it below your question. If I was doing it, I would use a linked list (instead of an array), and remove the word from the list once it's been used. If I were feeling lazy, I would set the word to "" after I used it, and check if the word is "" before showing it, if so, pick a different one. But this will introduce another problem into your code where you need to subtract one from `iter` I think. Linked list is a better choice.

Comment: Alternatively, try to remove it from the array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript