# How to remove array object from a variable in javascript by using for loop?

Tags: javascript

If the array position is not fixed, then how we remove the array ? I mean not using index/position. May be by using for loop. Position of the array is not fixed.

Comment: You have answered yourself ... for loop. Google javascript for loop and you will get plenty of examples

Comment: You do not show any efford that you've tryed to search over internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a duplicate, if you want to remove an item from an array, in the loop you need to do check on if say the BankBranchId == 6, if it is the you want to remove the object from the array.

Which is shown here -

[Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use splice to remove elements from an array, how to determine what is to be deleted. I think your `BankBranchId` is unique, so here it goes.

```
var removeBBID = 6;
for(key in bankBranchReponse) {
  if(bankBranchReponse[key].BankBranchId == removeBBID) {
    bankBranchReponse.splice(key, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use splice or pop.... array sequence is changing,,, could you please suggest anything other than using splice or pop function.

Comment: @AtDesk, I'm confused, you need not know the index of the object you want to remove. `removeBBID` is the `BankBranchId` value, within the object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the link what @JessicPartridge has given as her answer and what and @KBN has mentioned in his answer but there checking is happening on only one value of array!! Below code checks all the value and then removes array object from list!

```
for(var i=0;i<bankBranchReponse.length;i++)
{
    if(bankBranchReponse[i].BankBranchId === removeVariable.BankBranchId && 
       bankBranchReponse[i].BankBranchName===removeVariable.BankBranchName &&
       bankBranchReponse[i].isPaymentMade===removeVariable.isPaymentMade)
    {
                        bankBranchReponse.pop(bankBranchReponse[i]);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gcz1k29y/)**

Comment: I can't use splice or pop.... array sequence is changing,,, could you please suggest anything other than using splice or pop function.

Comment: changing in the sense!! Could you explain how??