# How to remove object from a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to remove object from array, I've tried and don't seem to be getting just right. So would someone be able to look at my code used

**Code:**

Array inside files ->

```
[{
  "favouriteLinkContent": "Group",
  "favouriteLinkID": "groupBTNFav"
}, {
  "favouriteLinkContent": "Server",
  "favouriteLinkID": "serverBTNFav"
}, {
  "favouriteLinkContent": "User",
  "favouriteLinkID": "userBTNFav"
}, {
  "favouriteLinkContent": "Sync",
  "favouriteLinkID": "syncBTNFav"
}]
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.removeFavourite', function ()
               {

  var buttonValue = $(this).closest('a')[0].innerText;

  // Reading
  $.ajax(
    {
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: (
        {
          action: 'read'
        }),
      url: 'php/saveFavouriteLinks.php',
      success: function (data)
      {

        $.each(data, function (key, value)
        {
          newValue = ' ' + value['favouriteLinkContent'];

          if (newValue == buttonValue)
          {
            console.log(value['favouriteLinkContent']);
            delete value['favouriteLinkContent']; 
          }
          //$("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id=" + value['favouriteLinkID'] + "><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> " + value['favouriteLinkContent'] + "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right removeFavourite'></i></a></li>");
        }); 
      }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Example of what I want happening**

Button Click -> Button value is Group -> Remove Group from Array ->

```
{"favouriteLinkContent":"Group","favouriteLinkID":"groupBTNFav"}
```

-> After deletion ->

```
[{
  "favouriteLinkContent": "Server",
  "favouriteLinkID": "serverBTNFav"
}, {
  "favouriteLinkContent": "User",
  "favouriteLinkID": "userBTNFav"
}, {
  "favouriteLinkContent": "Sync",
  "favouriteLinkID": "syncBTNFav"
}]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Tushar No need, I've just fixed it myself. My stupid mistake, I ended up putting the class on the wrong element. My mistake :)

Comment: @Tushar i've changed my question on this post, could you check it out?

Comment: on what basis do you want to remove the element from the array? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript ?

Comment: for removing element you can use [_slice_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [_splice_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) functions, and also you can use [_filter_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla i've updated my question to provide you with abit more information what I want happening

Comment: @Chris, you always want remove only one element, or a few elements?

Comment: @Grundy I want to remove the "favouriteLinkContent" and the "favouriteLinkID". Depending on which value gets passed

Comment: also, how you want use filtered array? possibly you not need remove, and just skip in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i].favouriteLinkContent === "Group"){ // <---- if you want to remove Group
    array.splice(i, 1); 
    i--;  // <--- have to do i-- because splice changes the array and array size will be altered
  }
}
```

You can wrap it in a function and remove the element from array based on the item

```
removeElement(arr, "Group");

function removeElement(arr, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].favouriteLinkContent === item) { 
      array.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: methinks you a bit confused with params and should be `array.splice(i,1);`, because first param: start index, and second - deleting count

Comment: me thinks you are right and thanks for correcting :)

Comment: Cheers @DhirajBodicherla for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper function with Array filter:

```
var removeObjectFromArray = function(array, property, objName){          
    return array.filter(function(e){
        return e[property] != objName;
    });
}


 console.log(removeObjectFromArray(array, 'favouriteLinkContent', 'Group'));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixcriv/c5m7su7q/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/filter

```
function removeGroup (arr, groupName) {
    return arr.filter(function (el) {return el.favouriteLinkContent !== groupName;});
}
```

Hope it helps,
Dan