# Javascript remove object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

so this question might be a little basic on the syntax level but I am new to javascript and still working things out.

So I set up an array that looks like this:

```
chainResidue = [ {cname : selectedId.ChainId, rnum: Numbed(selectedId.residueNumber}]
```

I will be pushing that to a separate array called ballsAndSticksData = []

like so:

```
ballsAndSticksData.push(picked);
```

I want to check if that item is in the list then if so remove it.

Full code:

```
$('span').click(function() {

                    // Index the span element relative to the Div Class
                    var index = $(this).index();
                    var selectedId = chainResidue[index];
                    //Set up the picked structure **Note** Not every PDB file starts off at the index of 1
                    var picked = structure.select({
                        cname: selectedId.chainId,
                        rnum: Number(selectedId.residueNumber)
                    });

                    // Check if the span element is selected or not
                    if ($(this).hasClass('spanSelected')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('spanSelected');
                        $(this).addClass('spanUnselected');

                        //Function to remove an element in a list
                        var index = ballsAndSticksData.indexOf(picked);
                        alert (index);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            ballsAndSticksData.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        console.log(ballsAndSticksData);
                        if ( ballsAndSticksData.length === 0 ) {
                            viewer.requestRedraw();
                        } else {
                            for (i = 0; i < ballsAndSticksData.length; i++) {
                                viewer.ballsAndSticks('ligand', ballsAndSticksData[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    }



                 else {

                        $(this).removeClass('spanUnselected');
                        $(this).addClass('spanSelected');
                        viewer.ballsAndSticks('ligand', picked);
                        ballsAndSticksData.push(picked);
                        console.log((ballsAndSticksData));

                    }
```

Things I have tried:

so the indexOf returns -1 everytime for the item in the list, so it must be something with the use of the {} which I thought was okay.

Comment: `indexOf` will only return something other than `-1` if it's the *exact same object*, not an object similar to one previously added.

Comment: For objects `indexOf()`  compares object references, which are obviously different. You'll need some kind of loop and do manual comparisons to remove your item.

Comment: how would I go about starting that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript

Comment: Remove an object by property value from an array: `[{x:0}, {x:1}, {x:2}].filter(element => element.x != 1);`

Comment: Thanks, that helps! and i got it to work!