# How to remove an object from an array without returning a new array while using native javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects such as Id:1, Name:Greg

Now I need to remove the object with an Id of 5.

I just need the existing array with the item removed, not a new array.

I don't want to use an external library to do this.

(The suggested duplicate answer is for deleting a number of objects at once, which is not what I want to do.)

What I would like to do is call

```
 remove(theArray, theObject);
```

and it would remove it from the array.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate tells you how to do this. You'll have to modify that code a little, but the main point is to use `.splice()`.

Comment: Ok, I will look at it more closely.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10024943/615754) from another question that is closer to yours (or other answers from that question).

Comment: Thank you, I voted up that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into array.splice method. You can pass it the index if object and 1 for delete count. This modifies the original array.

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.
>
> array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])

```
var index = items.indexOf(itemToFind);
items.splice(index, 1);
```