# Delete element in an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to delete element in an array of Object, look at my array:

I want delete the elements which have `done == true`, look at my script:

```js
var items = [{text: "a", done: false}, {text: "b", done: false}, {text: "c", done: true}, {text: "d", done: true}, {text: "e", done: true}];


items.forEach((elem, index) => {
  if(items[index].done) {
    items.splice(index, 1);
  }
})

console.log(items)
```

But it's doesn't work.

Comment: Use a reverse loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Comment: Well the problem is that you are iterating and removing elements from array at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter out things from an array. The best thing then is to use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
var items = [{text: "a", done: false}, {text: "b", done: false}, {text: "c", done: true}, {text: "d", done: true}, {text: "e", done: true}]

console.log(items.filter(o => !o.done))
```

The problem with your code is you are modifying the array while you are iterating over it, therefore when you remove an element all elements shift, and you skip the next element.

Check the following snippet, and how you never access the (d) element:

```js
var items = [{text: "a", done: false}, {text: "b", done: false}, {text: "c", done: true}, {text: "d", done: true}, {text: "e", done: true}]

var itemsCopy = [{text: "a", done: false}, {text: "b", done: false}, {text: "c", done: true}, {text: "d", done: true}, {text: "e", done: true}]

items.forEach((elem, index) => {
      if (itemsCopy[index].text !== items[index].text)
      console.log('you want to access', itemsCopy[index].text, 'instead you are accessing', items[index].text)
      if(items[index].done) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
        //elem.remove();
      }
  })
```

Every cycle the index increase by 1, so when you remove the `c` element, (index 2) then index becomes 3. But since you have deleted the `c`, now your array looks like:

`[a, b, d, e]`

Therefore you are accessing element `e`, not `d`, because now `d` has index 2

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question (namely - he modifies the array while iterating over it)

Answer (score 3):

This will not work because your are iterating and modifying the same array. When you delete an element at index 1, the element at index 2 become index 1 but your `forEach` will continue to iterate and will not check the new index 1

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

```js
var items = [{text: "a", done: false}, {text: "b", done: false}, {text: "c", done: true}, {text: "d", done: true}, {text: "e", done: true}];

items = items.filter(function(elem){
    return !elem.done;
});

console.log(items);
```