# Delete object from an array

Tags: javascript

Basically this is my object:

```
Object
    data:Array[4]
        0:Object
        1:Object
        2:Object
        3:Object
        length:4
        __proto__:Array[0]
        __proto__:Object
```

I want to delete 3rd object i,e `2:object`

This is what i am doing.

```
for(var arr in mainObj){
    var index =  Object.keys(mainObj).indexOf(arr);
    if(index == 2)
    {
        delete mainObj[arr];
    }

 }
```

This is not working. How to achieve this. Finally i should get.

```
Object
data:Array[3]
    0:Object
    1:Object
    2:Object
    length:3
    __proto__:Array[0]
    __proto__:Object
```

Comment: You can assign null and it wolud be deleted

Comment: `for(var arr in mainObj.data){` i guess you are missing `data` in the loop.

Comment: Can you please share the extact json object instead of copying from console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
mainObj.data.splice(2, 1);
```