# How to remove specific item from local storage array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'm building  a 'to do list' , The user appends new notes to the list after clicking .

I  saved all the appended data in the local storage.

Now i want to remove the clicked note from the array and save it back to the local storage.
I have this code:

```
    **//Here i get the note** 
    var getNote = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedNotes")) || [];
         $("#notes-section").append(getNote);

    **//Here i set the note** 
         getNote.push(note);
      localStorage.setItem("savedNotes", JSON.stringify(getNote)); 



 **//Here i want to remove the note from the array**
    $(document).on('click', '.pin', function() {
$(this).parent().css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 2000);

  for(var i =0 ; i < getNote.length; i++ ){

     getNote.splice(i,1);


       localStorage.setItem("savedNotes", JSON.stringify(getNote)); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code down to a _[mcve]_? Emphasis on minimal.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Thank you, Now its o.k ? (I'm new here..)

Comment: Much better. Shorter examples which show the issue help people answer your question quicker and more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments you need to provide only relevant code, but just to clear things out here, the way to go here is:

- To have an empty array of `notes`.
- Add this array to `localStorage` via `localStorage.setItem("savedNotes", JSON.stringify(notes))`.
- Every time you add a note you will need to: parse this array back from `localStorage` with `notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedNotes"))`.
- Then push the new `note` into this array via `notes.push(note)`.
- Then set this item again with `localStorage.setItem("savedNotes",
  JSON.stringify(notes))`, it will update your existing item in the localStorage.

It all relies on [**Storage.getItem()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and [**Storage.setItem()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) methods.

And to remove a `note` from the array you need to do the same thing, expect that you will search for this note in the parsed array and remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , But i still can't figure out how to do this ,can you please be more specific?

Comment: You need to loop throught the array, find the item to remove an dremove it from the array, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10024866/3669624).