# Remove some values of object from json

Tags: javascript

I have this json-

```
"SkuList": [
                    {
                        "active": null,
                        "id": 698027,
                        "productSKUName": "v1",
                        "productSKUDescription": null,
                        "productSKUId": "02ffea0f-3d05-44"
                    },
                    {
                        "active": null,
                        "id": 698028,
                        "productSKUName": "v2",
                        "productSKUDescription": null,
                        "productSKUId": "628acbb9-0bdb-4ccf"
                    },
              ]
```

How do I filter this json and return this -

```
"brandProductSkuList": [
                    {

                        "id": 698027,
                        "productSKUId": "02ffea0f-3d05-4436",
                    },
                    {

                        "id": 698028,
                        "productSKUId": "628acbb9-0bdb-4ccf"
                    },
                  ]
```

I want to remove certain properties of the object. How do I do this?

Comment: it's like create new object which takes the values you want.

Comment: Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```js
var SkuList = [
      {
          "active": null,
          "id": 698027,
          "productSKUName": "v1",
          "productSKUDescription": null,
          "productSKUId": "02ffea0f-3d05-44"
      },
      {
          "active": null,
          "id": 698028,
          "productSKUName": "v2",
          "productSKUDescription": null,
          "productSKUId": "628acbb9-0bdb-4ccf"
      },
];

var brandProductSkuList = SkuList.map((sku) => ({
  id: sku.id,
  productSkuId: sku.productSKUId
}));

console.log(brandProductSkuList);
```

Comment: Lol I wrote the same code. Did some silly mistake.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var newObj=SkuList.map(x=>({id:x.id,productSKUId:x.productSKUId}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = {"SkuList": [
                    {
                        "active": null,
                        "id": 698027,
                        "productSKUName": "v1",
                        "productSKUDescription": null,
                        "productSKUId": "02ffea0f-3d05-44"
                    },
                    {
                        "active": null,
                        "id": 698028,
                        "productSKUName": "v2",
                        "productSKUDescription": null,
                        "productSKUId": "628acbb9-0bdb-4ccf"
                    },
              ]
              
};

var output = input["SkuList"].map( o => (
  {"id" : o["id"],"productSKUId" : o["productSKUId"] }
));

var outputObject = {
  "brandProductSkuList": output
}

console.log(outputObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the array with [`Array#map()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw6rfU6IXVAhUKr48KHZXGArkQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg) function

```js
var arr = {"SkuList": [{ "active": null, "id": 698027,"productSKUName": "v1", "productSKUDescription": null,                      "productSKUId": "02ffea0f-3d05-44"},{"active": null,"id": 698028,               "productSKUName": "v2","productSKUDescription": null,                      "productSKUId": "628acbb9-0bdb-4ccf"},]}
              
 var res = {'brandProductSkuList':arr.SkuList.map(function(a){
     return ({id:a['id'],productSKUName: a['productSKUName'],})
 })}
 
 console.log(res)
```