# Remove all objects from array with a specific key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, each, splice

I've been literally struggling for a day, literally a whole day searching the entire stackoverflow and google to try and solve this issue but I'm desperate.
I've tried dozens of solutions but none of them seem to work...

I've got an array of objects where each object has a key named **pid** with a certain value.
Now I'd like to delete all objects with the same, specific **pid** value.

I've tried
`forEach, filter, $.each, $.grep` and many other functions to try to solve this issue, all of them unsuccessful (or maybe I'm doing something wrong every time?)

Simply, I want to remove each object with a specific **pid** value. My current code is:

```
$.each(cart, function(i){
        if(cart[i].pid === pid){
            cart.splice(i,1);
        }
    });
```

But this one keeps throwing: **Cannot read property pid of undefined**

Other functions delete only a (random?) amount of objects, there are still some left overs in the array with the unwanted **pid** value.

I don't necessarily have to stick with the `$.each` function, so any solution is greatly appreciated.

> Array of objects:

```
[{"id":1523898500862,"amm":1,"type":"t","name":"bluecheese","pid":1523898494726,"cost":0.5},{"id":1523898501937,"amm":1,"type":"t","name":"edam","pid":1523898494726,"cost":0.5},{"id":1523898505766,"amm":1,"type":"t","name":"mozzarella","pid":1523898494726,"cost":1}]
```

As you can see all the three objects hold the same **pid** value, I want to delete them all, according to that **pid**

Comment: Post your data.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), example data of the `cart` variable will make it easier to test.

Comment: If it is truly an object then than it shouldn't be possible to have duplicate keys.

Comment: I'll post the stringified data in a moment

Comment: The first parameter to the anonymous function is already the cart data, not the index.

Comment: @Sphinx, that will also fail because what is undefined it `cart[i]`, no `cart[i].pid`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Comment: what is `pid` in `cart[i].pid === pid`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is your solution. It takes a callback as an argument that decides if the element should be kept in the array and returns the filtered array.

```js
function remove(arr, pid) {
  return arr.filter(e => e.pid !== pid);
}

let arr = [{ pid: 1 }, { pid: 2 }];
console.log("Removed pid:1", remove(arr, 1));
console.log("Removed pid:2", remove(arr, 2));
console.log("Removed pid:3", remove(arr, 3));

let yourArr = [{
  "id": 1523898500862,
  "amm": 1,
  "type": "t",
  "name": "bluecheese",
  "pid": 1523898494726,
  "cost": 0.5
}, {
  "id": 1523898501937,
  "amm": 1,
  "type": "t",
  "name": "edam",
  "pid": 1523898494726,
  "cost": 0.5
}, {
  "id": 1523898505766,
  "amm": 1,
  "type": "t",
  "name": "mozzarella",
  "pid": 1523898494726,
  "cost": 1
}];
console.log("Removed from your array", remove(yourArr, 1523898494726));
```

Comment: This obviously doesn't work as it deleted only one instance in an array

Comment: This is strange.

Comment: I know. I've figured it out now. Thanks

Comment: An Important thing I learned was that the filter is already a loop.  It's going to loop through the whole array and delete anything that matches this case.  I had my filter in a for loop through the array previously.  That didn't work, this solution does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way which avoids any difficulties of modifying-while-iterating and good runs in good old O(n):

```
var removeByPid = function(cart, pid) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = cart.length; i < len; i++)
    if (cart[i].pid !== pid) result.push(cart);
  return result;
};
```

Now you can say:

```
var cart = /* ... get values for cart somehow ...  */

// ... Do more stuff ...

cart = removeByPid(cart, 1234);
```