# How to delete several tasks in a todo list with Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am building a todo list in Angular 5 and I'm trying to delete several tasks. Each task is a checkbox, if several tasks are checked all of theses tasks should be deleted at the same time when I click the button DELETE ALL (function deleteSelected). But sometimes it works, sometimes not I don't understand why.

Here's my code so far:

```
**todo.component.html**

<div class="main">
 <h1>To-do-list Alexandre, Cissé</h1>
 <div class="addItem">
  <form (ngSubmit)="addTodo()" #todoForm="ngForm">
   <input [(ngModel)] = "newTodo.newTodo" placeholder="Add a new todo" class="addText" name="newTodo">
   <button type="submit" class="btn-success">ADD</button>
  </form>
 </div>

<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let number = index">
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.status">
   {{todo.newTodo}}
   <button (click)="deleteTodo(number)" class="btn-warning">Delete</button>
 </li>
</ul>
<br />
 <button (click)="deleteSelected()" class="btn-danger">DELETE ALL</button>
</div>

**todo.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo';

@Component({
selector: 'app-todo',
templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})

export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  newTodo = new Todo();

  addTodo () {
    this.todos.push(this.newTodo);
    this.newTodo = new Todo();
     }

  deleteTodo (index) {
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
   }


  deleteSelected () {
    this.todos.forEach(function(value, index, object) {
    if (value.status === true) {

     //here I can't understand why it doesn't work

     object.splice(index, 1);
     }

     });
    }


   constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
   }

   }


   **todo.ts**

   export class Todo {
     static lastId = 0;
     public id: number;
     public newTodo: string;
     public status: boolean;

   constructor() {
     this.id = Todo.lastId + 1;
     this.status = false;
     Todo.lastId++;
       }
     }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try using the `filter` function instead to remove the ones you want to remove, e.g. `this.todos = this.todos.filter((todo) => todo.status != true)`, which will only keep todos where the status is not true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity in your case could be used [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
this.todos = this.todos.filter((todo)=> !todo.status);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `deleteSelected` function, instead of doing

```
object.splice(index, 1);
```

Use

```
this.todos.splice(index, 1)
```

Reference: **[Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024926/1417185)**