# Remove Element from Object list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list

How can I remove an element from an object list? 
I wish to remove the element `Kristian` from `someList`. For example:

```
someList = {"Kristian":"2,5,10",
             "John":"1,19,26,96"};
```

**I want to achieve:**

```
someList = {"John":"1,19,26,96"};
```

This is similar to [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript), but it's implemented differently and the solutions does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). You can use like so:

```js
const someList = {
  "Kristian": "2,5,10",
  "John": "1,19,26,96"
};

delete someList["Kristian"];
// OR: delete someList.Kristian;

console.log(someList);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `delete`.

```
delete someList.Kristian
```

Answer (score 1):

Use delete:

```js
const someList = {"Kristian":"2,5,10","John":"1,19,26,96"};
delete(someList.Kristian); // equivalent to   delete someList["Kristian"];
console.log(someList);
```