# Removing duplicate objects from array by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

so i have an array of objects, there are duplicate objects that contain the same id, i want to receive the first object with a unique id each time and then store that in a separate array. I Thought a map would achieve this but it dont seem to be working. I am using typescript.

My array of objects:

```
var infos= [

{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵", …}
{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Pitched Roof Window Buying Guide", Url: "buying-guide-pitched", Html: "<div class="background-grey" style="position: rela….&nbsp;</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Introducing Korniche Glass Lanterns", Url: "new-in-korniche-glass-lanterns", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…">&nbsp;</span>today!</strong></span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Introducing Korniche Glass Lanterns", Url: "new-in-korniche-glass-lanterns", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…">&nbsp;</span>today!</strong></span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Introducing Korniche Glass Lanterns", Url: "new-in-korniche-glass-lanterns", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…">&nbsp;</span>today!</strong></span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Introducing Korniche Glass Lanterns", Url: "new-in-korniche-glass-lanterns", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…">&nbsp;</span>today!</strong></span></p></div>
↵", …}
{InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "Introducing Korniche Glass Lanterns", Url: "new-in-korniche-glass-lanterns", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…">&nbsp;</span>today!</strong></span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 10, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "What are Heritage Conservation Roof Windows?", Url: "new-in-heritage-conservation-roof-windows", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…e more than happy to help you.</span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 10, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "What are Heritage Conservation Roof Windows?", Url: "new-in-heritage-conservation-roof-windows", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…e more than happy to help you.</span></p></div>
↵"}
{InfoPageId: 10, DepartmentId: 1, Name: "What are Heritage Conservation Roof Windows?", Url: "new-in-heritage-conservation-roof-windows", Html: "<div class="container py-4" data-jsplus-bootstrap-…e more than happy to help you.</span></p></div>
↵"}
]
```

logic:

```
 this.getUniqueValues(this.infos, 'InfoTypeId')


  getUniqueValues(infos: Array<infoPage>, comp: string ) {

                // store the comparison  values in array
                var unique =  infos.map(e => e[comp])

                // store the indexes of the unique objects
                .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

                // eliminate the false indexes & return unique objects
               .filter((e) => infos[e]).map(e => infos[e]);

               console.log(unique)

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

How about making it unique by making use of `Map`:

```js
var infos= [ {InfoPageId: 7, DepartmentId: 1 }, {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1 }, {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1 }, {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1 },]
var unique = [...new Map(infos.map(val=>[val.InfoPageId, val])).values()];

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` in conjunction with `Object.values`:

```
const uniqBy = (infos: InfoPage[], key: keyof InfoPage): InfoPage[] => {
  return Object.values(
    infos.reduce((unique, info) => ({
      ...unique,
      [info[key]]: unique[info[key]] || info,
    }), {} as any) // You could also improve the types of the function to get rid of the "any" but the amount of code might not be worth it
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. What you need to do is pick on element and check is there any element with the same `InfoPageId` in your selected array.

```js
var infos= [
  {InfoPageId: 7, DepartmentId: 1 },
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1 },
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 2 },
  {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1 },
]

const out = infos.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => acc.some(
        x => x.InfoPageId === cur.InfoPageId
    ) ? 
    acc : 
    acc.concat(cur),
    []
)

console.log(out)
```

In the above example I have used `reduce` and `some`. You can achieve the same with any other array looping method with the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
var infos= [ 
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1}
]

const uniqueInfos = []
const InfosMap = {}


infos.map((info) => {
  if (!InfosMap[info.InfoPageId]) {
    InfosMap[info.InfoPageId] = true
    uniqueInfos.push(info)
  }
})

console.log(uniqueInfos)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to achieve this as well.

```js
let infos= [ 
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 8, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1},
  {InfoPageId: 9, DepartmentId: 1}
];

const uniqueInfos = infos.filter((infos, index, self) => self.findIndex(i => i.InfoPageId === infos.InfoPageId && i.DepartmentId === infos.DepartmentId) === index);

console.log(uniqueInfos)
```

Comment: when im console logging the array it is empty, i have a feeling this may be because there is so much data in the array, would i have to load it asynch..

Comment: Yes. If your array is being fetched from a backend you would want to wait for it to completely load before performing any functions on it. I don't use angular but I assume it has a store that could hold this array and you can then use that stored array as you need.

Comment: hmm it dont seem to be that which is the issue, i wrapped the asynchronous call in a promise to make sure that the array is loaded before doing anything. but i still have issues

Comment: There could be an issue with how your `infos` data is structured. The double quotes in `html = "<div class="background-grey" style="position: re...etc""` could be making the infos array throw a syntax error. Is there any way you can change it to `"<div class='background-grey' style='position: re... etc'"`, ie with single quotes in the html string?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution would be to iterate through all items and keep a object of already processed items. and don't add already processed to new array.

```
public findUnique(data: any[], key: string): any[] {
  var result = [];
  var processedData = {};
  any.forEach((item) => {
     if(!processedData[item["key"]]) {
          result.push(item);
          processedData[item[key]] = true;
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```