# How to add and remove value from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following JSON,

```
[
   {
      "Id":163,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50031"
   },
   {
      "Id":161,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50029"
   },
   {
      "Id":160,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50028"
   },
   {
      "Id":159,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50027"
   }
]
```

If I pass `163`, I need to remove that node from the JSON, my expected output is,

```
[
   {
      "Id":161,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50029"
   },
   {
      "Id":160,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50028"
   },
   {
      "Id":159,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50027"
   }
]
```

AS well as I need to insert item to the JSON, if I pass following

```
   {
      "Id":164,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service8000"
   }
```

I need following JSOn output,

```
[
   {
      "Id":164,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service8000"
   },
   {
      "Id":163,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50031"
   },
   {
      "Id":161,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50029"
   },
   {
      "Id":160,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50028"
   },
   {
      "Id":159,
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "ServiceTypeId":"2",
      "ServiceName":"Service50027"
   }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {Id:163,CategoryId:"8",ServiceTypeId:"2",ServiceName:"Service50031"},
  {Id:161,CategoryId:"8",ServiceTypeId:"2",ServiceName:"Service50029"},
  {Id:160,CategoryId:"8",ServiceTypeId:"2",ServiceName:"Service50028"},
  {Id:159,CategoryId:"8",ServiceTypeId:"2",ServiceName:"Service50027"}
];

const removeRecordById = (arr, Id) => {
  const i = arr.findIndex(a => a.Id == Id);
  if (i > -1) arr.splice(i, 1);
};


removeRecordById(data, 163);
console.log(data);
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Sir how can I add item to array

Comment: and one more thing, this is not working in IE

Comment: Nice/Clean code. Small issue: `removeRecordById(data, "no-such-id);` return `-1`, meaning -n  (index of the nth last element). You get unexpected result (Remove the last array element).

Comment: @thomsan IE use is below 1.2% worldwide. https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @EzraSiton amazing catch. Thanks

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan awesome tool sir