# how to remove an object from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I created a dynamic objects array. and I want to remove object value from the array that's entered by the user. how to target each key and value indiviually please
any help

```
//get user iput in name field
var inputName = document.getElementById("name");
//get user iput in price field
var inputPrice = document.getElementById("price");
//get user iput in desc field
var inputDesc = document.getElementById("desc");
//form submition
var formSubmit = document.querySelector("form");
//get ul
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
//empty array to add inputted user data
var products = [];
//delete button
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");


//eventlistener on the form
formSubmit.addEventListener("submit", addProduct);

//form eventlistener function
function addProduct(e) {
    //to stop default form functions
    e.preventDefault();
    //create users input object
    var item = {
        title: inputName.value,
        desc: inputDesc.value,
        price: inputPrice.value
    } 
//add users input to products array
products.push(item);
ul.innerHTML = "";
console.log(products);
//loop over users input array
//add li items to the ul from users input
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    ul.innerHTML += "<li>" + products[i].title + products[i].desc + products[i].price + "</li>";
} 
}
```

Comment: Use `products.splice(i)` to remove the element at index `i`.

Comment: This question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript?rq=1) please check.